# Transition from WebForms to WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, webforms

I've only worked with .NET in a web environment, but I'd like to create a desktop app that will be a watered-down version of my web app, which will do some basic CRUD operations, send some e-mails, etc.

It's still .NET and C#, but it's the little things that sometimes cause the most trouble. I know I'll have to think differently about UI, there's no page lifecycle, and so on.

I was wondering if anyone had any tips or if there are any resources out there to help a developer change their mindset from web to desktop.

Comment: Don't worry, it's much easier than the other way around. ;-)

Comment: You might want to look at a tutorial for how to implement MVP (Model View Presenter) or MVC in WinForms. It might be overkill in a tiny application, but such tutorial will walk you through some of the important concepts of WinForms like where to put code, how event handlers work, etc.

Comment: Not worthy of an answer but follow a pattern such as MVP (Model View Presenter) and it'll be pretty similar to web development. The form(s) are just another view/way of looking at your data at the end of the day. I typed that before Albin's message loaded ;)

Comment: If you have never used WinForms and you are new, I think I would try to start using WPF instead, since that's what's new and coming. If you are new to it anyways, why not be new to what's new rather than what's old and then having to be new to what is new now later :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is through practice, and although it sounds corny, it is true. You can buy as many books on the subject as you want (and I'll suggest one or two), but the fastest way to learn is to dive right into the project. Just go ahead and create it. But first, play around a little with forms. Try dragging and dropping buttons onto a blank form, playing with event handlers, properties, etc. But then, I would just go for the project. You may need to redo it once you finish the first version of it (especially if it is something that is not just for fun), but hey, just another chance to learn.

**Book suggestion:**

For an in-depth look at C#, I would recommend this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Professional-4-0-NET-Wrox-Programmer/dp/0470502258/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1289338782&sr=8-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470502258)

It has chapters on Windows Forms and Graphics. It's massive and very helpful, although it targets C# 4.0. I don't really see many (up to date) books that focus primarily on Windows Forms, but once you get going with them (even at a very basic level), all the other more advanced Forms topics become much easier. Again, just start playing around with Forms. Luckily for you (and me, and everyone), Visual Studio makes it really easy to design forms. And if that's not what you are using, download the Express edition to try it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you going to WinForms? Try WPF!

In layout terms it has some similarities to Web, plus if you adopt MVVM there is some similarities to MVC and MVP.

And @SimpleCoder's comments also hold true.